# How to align text on the right side of an image in the header

Tags: html, css, image, text, alignment

[image]

So, I am trying to get the body text inside the red box that I added in the image attached. It seems like no matter what I do, it just keeps moving down.

Here is the code:

```html
<div class="catalog-center-width one-col-full">
  <div class="top-row-grey top-row-white-v2 padding-top padding-side row-v2">
    <div class="row dp-row-flex-v2">
      <div class="columns large-6 text-center dp-promo-image-wrapper"><img src="https://everpath-course-content.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/instructor%2F3vkvwjz9hnng2dhlfwzj2a5lt%2Fpublic%2F1666809704%2F6527-q2retarget-hc.1666809704408.png" alt="" width="529" height="360" align="left" /></div>
      <h1 class="break-word">
        <strong>Get started with Ally Lending basics</strong>
      </h1>
      <div class="sj-course-info-wrapper">
        <h2>Find and start conversations, collaborate effectively in channels, find information you need, keep work organized with channels and keep your sidebar organized in Slack.</h2>
        <div id="purchase-button-wrapper-large" class="purchase-button-wrapper">
          <a class="medium button purchase-button login-link free" href="/checkout/1ycnoni7kt1cn">
            <span class="purchase-button-full-text">&nbsp;Get Started </span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="purchase-button-wrapper-large" class="purchase-button-wrapper">
  <div id="purchase-button-wrapper-large" class="purchase-button-wrapper">
    <!-- START Walkthrough developer center tile design,
          add to page source code -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide full html and css so we can run and test your code.

Comment: You've messed up something in your css. Another issue is only having a fixed width and height through the default attributes of the image. This can also cause layout issues.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,body,h1,h2,h3 {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.container {
  width:100%;
  max-width:80vw;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  gap:4rem;
}

.left-col {
  width:30%;
}

.left-col img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}

.right-col {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  width:70%;
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-col">
    <img src="https://everpath-course-content.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/instructor%2F3vkvwjz9hnng2dhlfwzj2a5lt%2Fpublic%2F1666809704%2F6527-q2retarget-hc.1666809704408.png" alt="" width="529" height="360" align="left" />
  </div>

  <div class="right-col">
    <h1 class="break-word"><strong>Get started with Ally Lending basics</strong></h1>
    <h2>Find and start conversations, collaborate effectively in channels, find information you need, keep work organized with channels and keep your sidebar organized in Slack.</h2>
    <div id="purchase-button-wrapper-large" class="purchase-button-wrapper">
      <a class="medium button purchase-button login-link free" href="/checkout/1ycnoni7kt1cn"><span class="purchase-button-full-text">&nbsp;Get Started </span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="purchase-button-wrapper-large" class="purchase-button-wrapper">
  <div id="purchase-button-wrapper-large" class="purchase-button-wrapper">
    <!-- START Walkthrough developer center tile design,
          add to page source code -->
  </div>
</div>
```